# Django Can't access URL Pk from FormView Class

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am putting together a simple medical-related project that includes allowing user to order lab tests on a patient.  From the patient screen they select Order Tests. The UrlPattern, which includes the Patient pk, brings up the OrderTestsView which is a FormView.  The kwargs in this view have no pk even though it is in the Url.  I use a FormView because I need to access the list of tests selected in the Forms MultipleModelsChoice. But I need the patient information before the Order form is selected because I have to display who the patient is at the top of the order screen.  Normally I would use get_context_data to do all of this, but the kwargs are blank.  Not sure why FormView ignores the pk parameter, but how do I fix this?

```
urls.py
  path('order-tests/<pk>/', OrderTestsView.as_view(), name='order-tests'),

forms.py

class TestOrderForm(forms.Form):    
   choice = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Universal_Test_File.objects.all().order_by('test_name'), to_field_name="service_id")

view.py
class OrderTestsView(FormView):
    model = Universal_Test_File
    form_class = TestOrderForm
    success_url = '/list_tests/'
    template_name = "lab/order_tests.html"
    patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk)  ***## CANNOT ACCESS PK***

    def form_valid(self, form):
        choice = form.cleaned_data.get("choice")
        if choice:
            for test in choice:
                print(test.service_id, test.test_name)
```

Comment: try this `patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, self.kwargs['pk'])`

Comment: That does not work because the PK is not in kwargs.  That is the way I handle this issue in other types of Views but in the FormView kwargs is empty

Comment: Hello @Glenn try with `self.args['pk']`

Comment: args is also empty

Comment: patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])  in get_context_data is working. For some reason it failed earlier until I restarted the server. ??

Comment: Remove pk and give your field in `path()` in url like `path("order-tests/<id>/")` or give any primary key of your model other than `id`, and in your models define `pk_url_kwarg = id` or aything which is your model primary key name. Maybe, it might help.

Answer (score 0):

patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=self.kwargs['pk']) in get_context_data is working.  Not sure how I missed that??